# Change owner and group in C?

Tags: c, linux, chown

I want to change owner and group of a file in C. I google it, but if find only some code that use `system()` and `chmod` command or relative functions.

Is there a way to do this without `system()` functions and Bash commands?

Comment: The [GNU core utilities](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) (coreutils) package should have the source code for `chown`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [`chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html), `fchmodat` and/or [`fchmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fchmod.html) system calls. All three are located in `<sys/stat.h>`.

For ownership, there's [`chown`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chown.html) and `fchownat`, both in `<unistd.h>`.

Comment: Search for getuid/geteuid/getgid/getpwent/... and look at the related functions in `*pwent` docs. Also `getlogin` and `getpwnam`.

Answer (score 14):

To complete the answer, on Linux the following can be used (I've tested on `Ubuntu`):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <grp.h>

void do_chown (const char *file_path,
               const char *user_name,
               const char *group_name) 
{
  uid_t          uid;
  gid_t          gid;
  struct passwd *pwd;
  struct group  *grp;

  pwd = getpwnam(user_name);
  if (pwd == NULL) {
      die("Failed to get uid");
  }
  uid = pwd->pw_uid;

  grp = getgrnam(group_name);
  if (grp == NULL) {
      die("Failed to get gid");
  }
  gid = grp->gr_gid;

  if (chown(file_path, uid, gid) == -1) {
      die("chown fail");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `man 2 chown` and `man 2 chmod`.

Also see documentation [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chown.html) and [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html).

Comment: Yes, and more generally the original poster should read about Posix or Unix programming, and read the intro(2) and syscalls(2) man pages.

Comment: The man page for chown (at least, mine) doesn't tell you how to turn user and group names into integer ID's.

Answer (score 1):

`chown()` does the trick.

```
man 2 chown
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`chown`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/File-Owner.html) function in most C libraries:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int chown(const char *path, uid_t owner, gid_t group);
```